# How to manage collectstatic for Django app when deploying to multiple servers

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, deployment, collectstatic

My current setup:

- Multiple AWS Ec2 instances behind an elastic load balancer
- Django app source code in Github
- AWS S3 to host my static files
- CodeDeploy to clone repository onto new instances

I am using Docker to actually build the app on the instance. After the repository is cloned onto the instance, I build the docker image, inside of which I run my gunicorn server, and I forward port 80 requests to the image.

My question is regarding "collectstatic". Right now, I include "python manage.py collectstatic" in my Dockerfile as one of the build steps.

**The problem I am facing is that** collectstatic is currently run on each new instance during deployment, thus duplicating the work. It also results in collisions when new static files need to be uploaded to s3, or modified static files need to be updated. One instance will delete the file and begin copying it over, and the second instance will try to perform a read operation on a file that just got deleted, and will crash with *botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found*

**How should I be managing updating static files during deployment?** I would like to be able to run collectstatic only once during the deployment, but not sure how to integrate that with my current deployment via CodeDeploy, which does not seem to offer any pre-deployment hooks where I could run a custom script (CodeDeploy has per-instance hooks, but this would not help as I need something that happens on a given deployment, rather than on each instance created during the deployment)

Any help or advice would be appreciated. I am sure that there is something wrong here with respect to my setup, so any information or guidance on how static files are typically handled during deployment (when you have multiple instances you're deploying to) would be super helpful.

Comment: You could use the default file backend and run collectstatic on every ec2 instance when it is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem that you are building the docker image on all the target EC2 instances.

A better CI/CD flow will be that you build the docker image once then push the image to a container registry e.g. ECR. Also push any static files updates to S3.

Finally, to deploy on the target EC2 instances, you just pull the docker image and run it.

Comment: I considered that, but I felt like the image upload process was too slow, since the images are typically pretty large. Even so, I do think that's probably the way to go. Would I be pushing the image from my local environment, or would it from some build server like Jenkins or something?

Comment: You push image from the CI/CD build server. Optimize the image size, use a smaller base e.g. `alpine` and make sure you arrange layers properly. Also it will be slow for the first time only since common layers will already be on the docker registry